# Azure AD B2C in Blazor Server Application: Error during login after logout

Tags: azure, authentication, blazor, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side

I'm encountering a sporadic issue in my Blazor Server Application when integrating with Azure AD B2C for authentication. The problem seems to arise primarily when a user logs out and then gets redirected to the sign-in page. If they attempt to log in with different credentials, we frequently see the following error message:

**We are having trouble signing you in. Please try again later.**

Interestingly, if the user refreshes the page and tries to log in again, the login often succeeds without any issue.

Details:

Blazor Version: .NET 7
Athorization Config: FallbackPolicy - Require authentication for the entire app
Rerouting Config:

```
app.UseRewriter(
    new RewriteOptions().Add(
        context =>
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path == "/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignedOut")
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn");
            }
        }
        ));
```

Steps to Reproduce:

Log into the Blazor application using Azure AD B2C.
Log out from the application.
Get redirected to the Azure AD B2C sign-in page.
Try to log in with different credentials.

Has anyone else encountered this or a similar issue? Any help in troubleshooting or resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Thinking that the issue might stem from directly redirecting the user to the sign-in page after they've signed out, I modified my URL rewriting rule. I changed the redirect target from /MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn to the home route /.

Answer (score 0):

If the user logs out of the application and then tries to log in again with different credentials without refreshing the page. In this case, the application will still have the cookies from the previous login session, which can cause Azure AD B2C to reject the new login attempt.

Here is approach to redirect the user to the Azure AD B2C sign-in page after the user has logged out.
`AzureAdB2CAuthenticationBuilder.AddAccountSignedOutRedirect()` method to configure Azure AD B2C to automatically redirect the user to the sign-in page after they have logged out.
services.AddAuthentication(AzureAdB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
***program.cs***

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureAdB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAdB2C(options =>
    {   options.AddAccountSignedOutRedirect("/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn");
    });
```

***appsettings.json***

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "microsoft.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "TenantId",
    "ClientId": "ClientId",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "Client secret",
    "ClientCertificates": []
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**Output**

[image]

[image]

Comment: AzureAdB2CAuthenticationBuilder.AddAccountSignedOutRedirect() is based on the obsolete AzureADB2C.UI. I am using Identity,Web and Identity.Web.UI.

Comment: you can use following code




services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = async context =>
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn");
    };
});